# Ambulance and accident

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, random-variables

I have problems to solve this problem.

*An ambulance goes up and down on a street $L$ long at constant speed. At some point it happens an accident in a casual point of the street [It means that the distance between this point and the beginning of the street is distributed with uniform law $(0,L)$]. Assuming that the position of the ambulance at that moment, in an indipendent manner by the accident, it is itself distributed with uniform law $(0,L)$, calculates the distribution of her distance from the point of accident*.

Now, it's clear that I have to calculate the distribution of $Z=|X-Y|$ with $X \perp Y \sim U(0,L)$ but I'm having a hard time to handle the module and fix the extremes of integration. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS:**

$X$ takes any value between $0$ and $L$.  When is $Z<z$?  If $z<X<L-z$, we can say that $<X-z<Y<X+z$.  When $0<X<z$, we need $0<X<X+z$.  We need a similar adjustment at the high end of the range.

Now you should be able o write don the integrals.

Answer (score 1):

Given the position of the ambulance $x$, the expected distance between the ambulance and the accidence is

$$a(x) = \frac xL\cdot\frac x2 + \frac {L-x}{L}\cdot\frac {L-x}{2}
= \frac{1}{2L}(L^2-2xL+2x^2)$$

Then, the expected distance is,

$$D= \frac 1L \int_0^L a(x)dx = \frac13L$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain me based on what you wrote the first equality $\frac{x}{L}\cdot \frac{x}{2}+...$? Really, i don't understand.

Comment: @MarcoPittella - Sure, x/L is the probability of accidence left of x with x/2 the corresponding expected distance. Similarly, (L-x)/L is the probability of accidence right of x with (L-x)/2 the expected distance.